# Need help in understanding the solution to the C exercise involving pointers

Tags: c

I need help in understanding how we got the values in the table below for Loc3 and Loc4.
  When I was making a table on my own I arrived to totally different entries for those columns. 
  Thank you!

```
int x = 42; /* x is at address 100 */
int y = 13; /* y is at address 104 */
int *p; /* p is at address 108 */
int **p2; /* p2 is at address 112 */
/* Location 1 */
p = &y;
p2 = &p;
/* Location 2 */
*p2 = &x;
**p2 = 11;
/* Location 3 */
*p = 12;
/* Location 4 */
```

[image]

Comment: And *What* values do you get? How did you arrive at your values?

Answer (score 3):

For instance, x at loc3 becomes 11 because you set `**p2` to 11, which modifies the value at that memory location. (double star is a pointer to a pointer). Ampersand gets the address.

To elaborate:

```
*p2 = &x;
**p2 = 11;
```

In Loc2 you set `p2 = &p`, which means `p2` is now pointing to the address of `p`, which is 108.

But now in Loc3, you set what `p2` is pointing to to the address of `x`. In other words, since `p2` was pointing to the address of `p`, now you're saying that `p` should instead point to the address of `x` (which is also why `p` becomes 100).

Then `**p2` modifies the value at that address of `x` to be 11 (through `p`), hence loc3's `x` value becomes 11.

Answer (score 1):

*Location 1:*

```
int x = 42;
int y = 13;
int *p;
int **p2;
```

`p` or `p2` don't point anywhere.

*Location 2:*

```
p = &y;
```

`p` points to `y`.

```
p2 = &p;
```

`p2` points to `p`.

No changes to x or y.

*Location 3:*

```
*p2 = &x;
```

Since `p2` points to `p`, dereferencing `p2` and assigning a value to it changes `p` to point to `x`. Same as doing `p = &x`.

```
**p2 = 11;
```

Dereference once to get to `p`, dereference again to get to `x`, and assign 11 to it. Same as doing: `x = 11` or `*p == 11`.

No change to `y` or `p2`.

*Location 4:*

```
*p = 12;
```

Dereference `p` to get to `x` and assing 12 to it. No change to `y` or `p2` or `p`.

Answer (score 0):

When you start out, `p` and `p2` are uninitialized and contain indeterminate values, hence the `??` in both entries under Loc 1.

```
p = &y;
```

assigns the *location* of `y` (104) to `p`.

```
p2 = &p;
```

assigns the location of `p` (108) to `p2`.  Note that the type of the *expression* `&p` is `char **`, which matches the type of the *variable* `p2`.  So after these two statements, all of the following are true:

```
  p2 == &p       == 108  // all expressions have type char **
 *p2 ==  p == &y == 104  // all expressions have type char *
**p2 == *p ==  y == 13   // all expressions have type char
               x == 42
```

Next we execute

```
*p2 = &x;
```

From above we see that `*p2` is equivalent to `p`, so this statement assigns the address of `x` (100) to `p`, so now we have

```
  p2 == &p       == 108
 *p2 ==  p == &x == 100       
**p2 == *p ==  x == 42
               y == 13
```

Next we execute

```
**p2 = 11;
```

`**p2` is equivalent to `*p`, which is equivalent to `x`, so we wind up assigning the value 11 to `x`:

```
  p2 == &p        == 108
 *p2 ==  p == &x  == 100
**p2 == *p ==  x  == 11
               y  == 13
```

Finally we have

```
*p = 12;
```

`*p` is equivalent to `x`, so we're assigning the value 12 to `x`, leaving us with:

```
  p2 == &p        == 108
 *p2 ==  p == &x  == 100
**p2 == *p ==  x  == 12
               y  == 13
```